# Angular: No pipe 'translate' was found

Tags: angular, typescript, translate, angular-translate

I need to use the translate pipe in my project. In my `app.module`, I have:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    FormsModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
      
  }), // .forRoot(),
  TranslateModule
  
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './languages/', '.json');
}
```

But in my app-component (and every child where I have this)  where I try use the `translate` pipe:

```
 <div id="port_header">
            <a id="portal-logo-header" title="{{ 'APPLICATION.FRONT_OFFICE.HEADER.HOME' | translate }}">
                <img src=" alt="">
            </a>
```

I get `No pipe found with name 'translate'`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Otter I need to use angulart 'translate' pipe, it isn't my  own pipe

Comment: Oh whoops, my bad. It looks like you might be defining your custom translation function incorrectly: Have you tried defining it above **@NgModule**? Additionally, have you tried removing the random `TranslateModule` below your `imports` object? Those two *look* incorrect. I'm totally spitballing here according to what I see in the [ngx-translate docs](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#aot)

Comment: I tried reproducing your error, but everything seems to be working. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-67521001?file=src/app/app.component.html You're not telling us the whole story, so we cannot help. This is why you're supposed to create a reproduction when asking.

Comment: Usually a no pipe found, means you did not import the module on the right "spot"
Your definition might be ok, but maybe you need to import the translation module on the component module you're testing

Comment: I'm also getting this error but it's non-deterministically. It seems like problem with webpack cache, because deletion of .angular directory only helps.